# Android different selection spinner show different textview

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, android-spinner

I would like my spinner to show a different textview for different selections choosen on my spinner in Android Studio. Its a drug interactions application so when a user chooses a drug from the spinner i would like a different interaction to appear for each one.
Any suggestions would be useful.

Below is my code,

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    Spinner spinner;
    TextView showmed;
    private String[] state = {"Adalimumab",
            "Etanercept",
            "Tacrolimus",
            "Mycophenolic Acid",
            "Bicalutamide",
            "Darbepoetin alfa",
            "Ciclosporin",
            "Interferon beta-1a",
            "Triptorelin"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        System.out.println(state.length);
        showmed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showgender);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, state);
        adapter_state
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter_state);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

     }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                               long id) {
        spinner.setSelection(position);
        String selState = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
        showmed.setText("Your drug:" + selState);
     }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Comment: Do you want to update your list or to create a pop-up sub menu for every drug?

Comment: not a sub menu really. My spinner has a drop down list of 6 drugs and I want a textview to change every time someone chooses a different drug from the drop down list as there are different interactions for each drug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the approach you might been looking for:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                           long id) {

               switch(position)
{

               case 0:
               showmed.setText("Your drug number 0 on the list");
                break;

               case 1:
               showmed.setText("Your drug number 1 on the list");
                break;

}


 }
```

You also should update to `final TextView showmed;`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a listener on the spinner:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

The method to implement will look like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    if(position == 0)
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //do something similar for every position
}
```

Based on the position that is passed to that method, you can change the visibility of your textviews to gone or visible.

Comment: You can use textView.setText("<YourNewText>") instead of setVisibility

Comment: i posted my code above in an answer, do you think I could still use this code?

Answer (score 0):

Check the drug name and based on the drug name set

```
adapter_state.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_text_view)
```

here R.layout.custom_text_view is the XML which u will make as in how u will like

Answer (score -1):

This is my code if it helps. Could i still use this code?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
Spinner spinner;
TextView showmed;
private String[] state = {"Adalimumab",
        "Etanercept",
        "Tacrolimus",
        "Mycophenolic Acid",
        "Bicalutamide",
        "Darbepoetin alfa",
        "Ciclosporin",
        "Interferon beta-1a",
        "Triptorelin"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    System.out.println(state.length);
    showmed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showgender);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, state);
    adapter_state
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter_state);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

 }

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                           long id) {
    spinner.setSelection(position);
    String selState = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
    showmed.setText("Your drug:" + selState);
 }

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: i posted my code below in an answer, do you think I could still use this code?